# modrewrite to remove the file extension but still load the page

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, web

I have a subdomain with .php pages in it.  I just want to remove the .php  I have written some code gathered from other posts on stack, so far I have this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.php(.*)\sHTTP/1)
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

this rewrites 
subdomain.example.com/weddings.php

to

subdomain.example.com/weddings

However it also creates a 404 page not found error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  anyone struggling with the same thing here is my solution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

found it on

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/remove-file-extention-from-urls/

a fantastic website.